# Doesn't NumPy/SciPy have complex numbers of "int" type?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am writing NumPy/SciPy routines for processing spectra, which consist of complex numbers.

According to what I found from the following website, it seems that the only complex number formats are floating-point formats.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

However, I'd like to make a routine which can also handle spectra in fixed-point format.

Are there any easy ways to do this?

Comment: Could you provide more context? Why are you looking for fixed point variables? Usually integer arithmetic has terrible performance when compared to floating point, so there should be a strong case for using integers (or other representations) instead of IEEE floating point numbers.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is *no*.

Comment: You could defined a structured (compound) `dtype`, with the 2 parts as 'real' and 'imaginary' fields.  But it wouldn't have all the mathematical machinery that the float version does.